# Jenkins and monitoring artefacts (like jupyter notebooks)

Tags: python, jenkins, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, data-science

What approach would be the best for the following task?
We use Jenkins for running data science experiments (experiment = jenkins build).

I would like to have (for a job I would configure) each build to display either:
a) its produced jupyter notebook (the job had done as a part of the build). Maybe this is called 'build artifact'? Am I right?
b) live (like it is monitoring stdout on 'console output') jupyter notebook view, that the build is running.
(For people not familiar with ipython notebooks - the build would, as a part of pipeline just start the jupyter notebook server using bash command and run a specific file. The jupyter service then creates -at the node it is running on- a localhost webserver on a a specific port ... and I want this web-app output of the port displayed in jenkins->job->build ... meybe on a plugin's page, i do not want to overwrite consoleoutput, of course)

Is there already a plugin for that? Or should I make my own one? Or should it be way easier using some trick?
What is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to build your project, pull any dependency if required (i.e. pip/conda install ...), and perhaps use [nbviewer](https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer) to render a static version of your notebook?

That way, you could either get it running from slaves with the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) right from your Jenkins node, or push to S3, internal web server, etc.

If you **have** to run the notebook, I would avoid running it from the slave. It may work initially, but with time, that will make it harder for you to distribute the load of builds if you use the node resources for serving the notebook as well.

Hope that helps
Bruno

Comment: Thanks for an idea for a way, I will look at HTML publisher! The problem is, that jupyter generates new adress each time it is run... anyway, I already pip install all requirements in my job, so that is OK. Actually I really want to run the notebook, because I use Jenkins as a resource manager for nodes and their gpus (to automate things to not need to use ssh at my computer ever ;) ) As for 'I would avoid ' -> we actually use the nodes resources to serve notebooks now, so it is only a step forward :) I think it is a difference between ops for builds and ops for machine learning.

Comment: Looked at the html publisher and it does not allow displaying things while the job runs unfortunately (I would justn eed jenkins to display me, probably with my own plugin...?, the contents of the node's localhost:8080 in a tab or somewhere I could see it from my browser - cannot link directly to localhost:8080 from my browser obviously :) )